# How to handle rude language?

Tags: mindfulness, right-effort, right-intention

How to speak or act with a pure thought when people tell joke and use rude language towards you, trying to upset you according to Buddhist teachings?And how to change the unwholesome thought to wholesome when the mind is full of hatred and aversion and  cultivate loving kindness?I hope this make sense.

Comment: Similar question: http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3834/how-to-deal-with-people

Comment: Hmm... looks like a duplicate, from the same person even, thanks for pointing that out Thiago, I will merge the questions.